# TAB should indent at start of line and advance to tab stop otherwise

Tags: indentation, align

More precisely, I would like `TAB` to indent the current line when there are 0 or more whitespace characters between the start of line and the point and to advance to the next tab stop otherwise. I used to have this behavior 1 or 2 major versions ago, but I lost it in an upgrade (I'm currently using 27.2).

I tried customizing `tab-always-indent` to `nil` as defined in [indent.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/indent.el), but I think the programming mode is overriding this behavior (I primarily deal in curly-brace languages).

I use this behavior to create "columns" in my source. i.e.

```
private int       able;
private boolean   baker;

public    int       getAble()                    { return able; }
public    boolean   getBaker()                   { return baker; }
```

Turns out I needed to pay closer attention to the description when customizing tab-always-indent and customize c-tab-always-indent as:

> Some programming language modes have their own variable to control this,
> e.g., 'c-tab-always-indent', and do not respect this variable.

Comment: What's the output of `C-h c <TAB>` and `C-h v <tab-always-indent>`, both with your Emacs setup and when starting it without customizations (e.g.`$ emacs -Q`)? What is the major-mode of the buffer?

Comment: That set of questions from Y. E. led me to the right answer. I should have paid more attention when I customized tab-always-indent. The bottom of the descriptions reads:

   "Some programming language modes have their own variable to control this,
   e.g., ‘c-tab-always-indent’, and do not respect this variable."

customizing c-tab-always-indent fixed by problem for java

Comment: Please write a quick Answer explaining the solution to that problem, and then you can Accept your own answer.  This will help future readers who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more careful reading of the customize description for `tab-always-indent` points to **`c-tab-always-indent`** as controlling this behavior for the c programing family (c, c++, java, probably c#).

> Controls the operation of the TAB key.
> If t, hitting TAB always just indents the current line.
> If nil, hitting TAB indents the current line if point is at the left margin
> or in the line’s indentation, otherwise it inserts a "real" TAB character.
> If ‘complete’, TAB first tries to indent the current line, and if the line
> was already indented, then try to complete the thing at point.
>
> Some programming language modes have their own variable to control this,
> e.g., ‘c-tab-always-indent’, and do not respect this variable.